# Changing the return type and also the last number to be printed

Tags: java

I have the below java program which prints all the prime numbers till 100, now I want to modify the same so that user will enter the number and it will print not the range but the very last prime number exists in that range, please advise how to modify the below program also I want to change the return type from string to int that is

```
 class PrimeNumbers
 {
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {        
       int i =0;
       int num =0;
       //Empty String
       String  primeNumbers = "";

       for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)         
       {              
          int counter=0;      
          for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
      {
             if(i%num==0)
         {
        counter = counter + 1;
         }
      }
      if (counter ==2)
      {
         //Appended the Prime number to the String
         primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
      } 
       }    
       System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to 100 are :");
       System.out.println(primeNumbers);
   }
}
```

right now the output is

```
Prime numbers from 1 to 100 are :
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

and I want only last prime number to be printed only

```
100
```

Comment: Just reverse your loop order, i.e.`for(i = 100; i>1;i--)`. When you find a prime, `break;` the loop

Comment: The return type is `void` and not `String`. It's obvious that you have copy/pasted this homework from someone else  :(

Comment: @Jason The logic actually looks to be correct.  Suggesting that `100` is prime is incorrect or a typo, but the OP's should never generate that.

Answer (score 0):

Try just maintaining state for the most recent prime number discovered by the loop:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int prime;

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {         
        int counter = 0;      
        for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
             if (i % num == 0) {
                 counter = counter + 1;
             }
        }
        if (counter == 2) {
            prime = i;
        } 
    }    

    System.out.println("Last prime number from 1 to 100 is: " + prime);
}
```

Comment: Dude.  We like to work people towards the answer rather than giving to him/her when it's simple stuff like this.  Helps them learn instead of just finishing their homework. - just your description was PERFECT!

Comment: @Steve You mean to say that my job _isn't_ to do everyone's homework?  I wish you had told me this 5 years ago when I started contributing.

Comment: Ha!   Well, there are actually arguments both ways.  But the site leaders/owners say they'd like to not just do people's homework for them if possible. - I just today had this great little implementation put together, and then one of the big guys closed the question before I could post my answer.  I though the question was pretty narrow and reasonable, but @Hovercraft told me that it was doing someone's homework for them.  The guy fought, saying he wasn't doing homework, and Hovercraft swore that he was.  It was fun stuff ;)  Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to introduce a `int` variable (`int primeNumber`) that will hold the value of the largest prime number. Made some minor changes in problem code:

```
int i = 0;
int num = 0;
//Empty String
int primeNumber = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {        
    int counter=0;      
    for(num =i; num>=1; num--) {
        if(i%num==0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
    if (counter ==2) {
        primeNumber =  i;
    } 
}    
System.out.println("Largest Prime number from 1 to 100 is : ");
System.out.println(primeNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding ,you want to print the max prime number which is closed to 100.

```
 class PrimeNumbers
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {        
   int i =0;
   int num =0;
   //Empty String
   String  primeNumbers = "";

   for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)         
   {              
      int counter=0;      
      for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
   {
         if(i%num==0)
     {
    counter = counter + 1;
     }
  }
  if (counter ==2)
  {
     //Appended the Prime number to the String
     primeNumbers =  i+ "";
  } 
   }    
   System.out.println("Max prime number between 1 to 100 is:");
   System.out.println(primeNumbers);
  }
}
```

UPDATE :

This program can be further optimized to improvise time complexity

```
public class  PrimeNumbers{

 public static void main (String[] args)
{        
int i =0;
int num =0;

int  primeNumbers = 0;

for (i = 100; i >= 1; i--)         
{              
  int counter=0;      
  for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
{
     if(i%num==0)
 {
  counter = counter + 1;
 }
}
if (counter ==2)
 {
  primeNumbers =  i;
  break;
 } 
}    
 System.out.println("Max prime number between 1 to 100 is:");
 System.out.println(primeNumbers);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed source codes can be written more structured:

```java
public class PrimeNumbers {
    private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n == 2) return true;
        if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i = i + 2)
            if (n % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int biggestPrimeNumber = 0;
        String primeNumbers = "";
        for (int n = 2; n <= 100; n++)
            if (isPrime(n)) {
                biggestPrimeNumber = n;
                //Appended the Prime number to the String
                primeNumbers += n + " ";
            }
        System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to 100 are: " + primeNumbers);
        System.out.println("Last prime number from 1 to 100 is: " + biggestPrimeNumber);
    }
}
```

For checking the primality of a number there are many algorithms like [Miller–Rabin primality test](http://Miller%E2%80%93Rabin%20primality%20test)[Miller%E2%80%93Rabin%20primality%20test]) but a simple brute force way is to check numbers up to sqrt of the desired number.